# OCI CLI fails to load default profile from config file even if I have proper default profile

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

When I run any oci cli command I'm getting below error:

```
ERROR: Profile '<DEFAULT>' not found in config file C:\Users\user1\.oci\config
```

Below is my config file for OCI CLI:

```
[DEFAULT]
user=<admin user ocid>
fingerprint=<fingerprint>
key_file=<path/to/private/key>
tenancy=<tenancy ocid>
region=ap-mumbai-1
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem to this. If you use Python and have changed some of the libraries it's possible you may have updated some of the needed dependencies. Upgrade/reinstall oci ie.

```
pip install oci-cli --upgrade
```

This sorted the problem for me.

Comment: It solved for me. Thank you.

Comment: My problem was an incompatibility with a newer Click Python package: https://github.com/oracle/oci-cli/issues/440

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a backup of this config file, delete it and reconfigure CLI automatically by executing "oci setup config"

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this document on [Configuring the CLI](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/cliconfigure.htm) and tally it with the config file of yours.

And refer the discussion in this forum [OCI Config not found issue](https://github.com/oracle-quickstart/oci-cis-landingzone-quickstart/issues/14), this might be useful as well.

Comment: Before posting the question, I've gone through all the documentation and config file same as it is in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I guest that you are using pacman to install oci-cli. You should remove it and reinstall with official method.

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/cliinstall.htm

```
bash -c "$(curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oracle/oci-cli/master/scripts/install/install.sh)"
```